# Spring data findAllBy with iterable returns empty array

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongo

Using a `ReactiveMongoRepository` and a custom method to return all objects with the matching property is returning a empty collection on anything other than the `findAllById` call.

I'm wondering if I just misunderstood something here and this only works on the ID field or something?

The interface I'm using:

```
@Repository
public interface VideoRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Video, String> {
    Flux<Video> findAllByHash(Iterable<Long> hash);
}
```

And I'm just calling that via:

```
@GetMapping("duplicates")
public Flux<Video> duplicates() {
    // {...}

    List<Long> hashList = duplicateDTOs
            .stream()
            .map(duplicateDTO -> Long.valueOf(duplicateDTO.getHash()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return videoRepository.findAllByHash(hashList);
}
```

For reference, the POJO in question:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Video {

    @Id
    String id;

    long hash;

    //{...}
}
```

I have confirmed I'm passing in three values in the `hashList` which match the custom `hash` property set on the `Video` POJO.

Should this not return all `Video` objects which have the matching custom `hash` property as it does when I do the same thing but for the `id` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findAllByHashIn(Collection<Long> hashes);
```

I've never used an `Iterable` as a parameter to a custom JPA repository method before, but I would translate the name `findAllByHash` as "take *a single hash value* and find all entries possessing that value" and the signature would be `findAllByHash(Long hash)`.

Your motivation is a bit different: you want *all hashes* to be used during the search. According to [this table](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation),

```
Keyword | Sample                             | JPQL snippet

In      | findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages)  | … where x.age in ?1
```

Spring JPA support logical `IN` and accepts a subclass of `Collection`, so it could be

```
findAllByHashIn(Collection<Long> hashes);
findAllByHashIn(List<Long> hashes);
```

**Update**

Out of curiosity, I wrote own `Iterable` which isn't a `Collection` to see the method fail. As expected, Spring threw

> IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value XXX did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)].

Although it expects a `Long` parameter, it runs well with a `Collection` (I used `Arrays.asList(1L, 2L)`), but executes a silly SQL query:

```
... from XXX XXX0_ where XXX0_.hash=(? , ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [2]
```

With `findAllByHashIn`, `IN` is added and the query looks nice:

```
... from XXX XXX0_ where XXX.hash in (? , ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [2]
```

Comment: That is very interesting, I am able to successfully make use of `Flux<Video> findAllByHashIn(Iterable<Long> hash);` with no errors and the correct values being returned. Thank you though for spotting my obvious mistake, I've clearly been awake to long now.

Comment: @ChrisTurner happy to help :) I still don't recommend using `Iterable` as a method param though